# General way of handling "an error occurred while the batch was being executed"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

When I run the `.publish.xml` of my SQL Server Database Project, I get the following error:

> an error occurred while the batch was being executed"

There's an incredible amount of questions asking what to do for that error, but they know their changes and the answers are always very individual.

How do I solve this, if it's not clear which change caused the error? Of course it should never get to that point, but sooner or later in a big project someone will mess up and it will come to that. Can I get better error messages out of Visual Studio? It's not even telling me which table caused this, it doesn't stop and just keeps executing. Just a typo turns into a goose chase.

Am I missing something? Should I not use the SQL Server Database Project / publish file?

Comment: Have you tried generating the update script and running that directly?

Comment: That error alone is not useful. There must be a way to get more detail on what error occurred, what line it occurred on